# In passivizing "The children bought the dolls", should I use 'by' or 'for the children'?

Tags: passive-voice

Active:  The children bought the dolls.

Passive:

> The dolls were bought **for** children.

*or*

> The dolls were bought **by** children.

Which is the best and correct sentence? 
I am confused here.

Comment: Have you looked up how the passive is formed?

Comment: Are these example answers from a textbook and you need to pick one or the other? Which would you pick - what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

"The dolls were bought by the children" is the correct passive form of your first sentence -- it is still the children that are buying the dolls.

"The dolls were bought for the children" has a different meaning than the Active sentence: it's saying that someone else, not the children, bought the dolls.

Finally, note that I've added "the" before "children" to make the Passive sentences as comparable as possible to the Active sentence.